# Error 503 on Varnish on Setup

Tags: drupal-7, varnish, http-status-code-503

I have set up Varnish on my centos server which runs my drupal site.
Browsing to any page returns a blank page due to 503 :Service Unavailable

I have read many questions and answers about intermittent 503's but this is occurring constantly. I can still browse to the site using www.example.com:8080 .

I am running on Centos 6 using the VCL : 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NITEMAN/Varnish_VCL_samps-hacks/master/varnish3/drupal-base.vcl

I have also tried https://fourkitchens.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TECH/Configure+Varnish+3+for+Drupal+7 .

Not sure where to even start in debugging this.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
NITEMANS answer below provides some really helpful debug suggestions.
In my case it was something very simple, I had left the default 127.0.0.1 in my default.vcl . Changing this to my real external IP got things working. I hope that is the correct thing to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're running my sample VCL, it should be easy to debug (try each step separately):

- Make sure apache is listening on 127.0.0.1:8080 (as it can be listening on another IP and not in the local loopback). `netstat -lpn | grep 8080` should help.
- Rise backend timeouts (if the server is very slow, since defined timeouts are already huge). Requires a Varnish reload.
- Disable health probe (as Varnish can be marking the backend as sick). Comment `probe basic` block and probe line on `backend default`. Requires a Varnish reload.
- Disable Varnish logic, uncommenting the first `return(pipe)` on `sub vcl_recv`. Requires a Varnish reload.

You should also provide when debugging:

- `varnishadm debug.health` output
- `varnishlog` output for a sample request

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you NITEMAN. Your debug advice was just what I needed, and your VCL is the perfect, the annotations really help.